# How to loop over a cell array of variables and perform an operation on each one of them?

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array of variables called bin_this. I need to loop over it, access each variable, bin the data in that variable, and place the binned data into a newly created variable.
So if the array contains a, b, c....etc.
I would need to create a new set of binned variables
a_bin, b_bin, c_bin etc.
without destroying the old ones

Comment: Do you mean cell array or structure array? Structure arrays have field names. Cell arrays don't.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is a cell array, here's how to loop over it:

```
bin_this = {[1, 2, 3, 4],[5, 6, 7, 6],[1, 2, 3, 7]} % example data
s = size(bin_this)

binnedResults = cell(s);
for t = 1:s(2)
    data = bin_this{t}; % access data
    binnedData = hist(data); 
    binnedResults{t} = binnedData; %store data
end
```

If your data is a structure array, and you want to add fields to it, here's how to do that:

```
bin_this = struct('a', [1, 2, 3, 4], 'b', [5, 6, 7, 6], 'c', [1, 2, ...
                    3, 7]);
newFields = struct('a','a_bin','b','b_bin','c','c_bin'); % define the new field names 


fields = fieldnames(bin_this);  % get the field names from bin_this
for t = 1:length(fields)
    f = fields{t}; 
    data = bin_this.(f); % get the data with a particular field name
    binnedData = hist(data); 
    newField = newFields.(f); % get the new field name
   bin_this.(newField) = binnedData; % add the binned data to the original structure with
                                     % a new field name. 
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Molly! The cell array actually contains names of variables. I need to open the variables. Bin the data that they contain (using hist(data, xcenters)) and then place the newly binned data into a new variable.                                                  So let's say my cell array is called bin_this. It contains the names of variables. So bin_this contains a,b,c,d,e,f...etc. (the variable names). I need to open a,b,c...etc. and bin each one of them and then reassign them to new variables a_bin, b_bin etc. And I have to do this without destroying a,b etc. (original vars)

Comment: By open the variables, do you mean open .mat files? Or do these variables already exist in the work place?